# Add header to HTTP Post content Flume

Tags: hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I am testing out Flume HTTP Source with HDFS as sink. Below is the conf file used.

```
httpagent.sources = httpsource 
httpagent.sinks = hdfs-file-sink
httpagent.channels = ch3

httpagent.sources.httpsource.type = http 
httpagent.sources.httpsource.bind = address 
httpagent.sources.httpsource.handler =org.apache.flume.sink.solr.morphline.BlobHandler httpagent.sources.httpsource.channels = ch3 
httpagent.sources.httpsource.port = port


httpagent.sinks.hdfs-file-sink.type = hdfs 
httpagent.sinks.hdfs-file-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:8020/flume/events 
httpagent.sinks.hdfs-file-sink.hdfs.fileType=DataStream 
httpagent.sinks.hdfs-file-sink.hdfs.filePrefix = events- 
httpagent.sinks.hdfs-file-sink.hdfs.rollInterval = 30 
httpagent.sinks.hdfs-file-sink.channel = ch3 
httpagent.channels.ch3.type = memory
```

The request body is getting saved in HDFS. But I want to append the HTTP headers as well to the post content. how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at event serializers ( https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#event-serializers )

Serializer can be set as described at https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink

If you want the headers, you should either go with Avro Event Serializer or write a custom one.